# CustomView with squiggle(wavy) top.(Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibezierpath

I am trying to create a custom view a squiggle top and add an image view in the middle.

**Something like this:**

[image]

But I am not so used to `UIBezierPath`, so I am pretty confused.

> This is what I have done so far.

```
    class DemoView: UIView {

  var path: UIBezierPath!

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
      super.init(frame: frame)

      self.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    complexShape()
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    complexShape()
  }

    func complexShape() {
        path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2 - 50.0, y: 0.0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: 0.0))
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width, y: 50.0),
                      controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width + 50.0, y: 25.0),
                      controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width - 150.0, y: 50.0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width, y: self.frame.size.height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: self.frame.size.height))
        path.close()

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath


        self.layer.mask = shapeLayer
    }

}

extension CGFloat {
    func toRadians() -> CGFloat {
        return self * .pi / 180.0
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it that you are asking ? You havent asked a question ? What do you want the bezier path to do ? do you want an animation ? Do you want the red box to move ? Your question is not clear as to what you are asking help on

Comment: Take a look at: https://www.raywenderlich.com/776399-core-graphics-tutorial-curves-and-layers

Comment: @JulianSilvestri I don't want to move anything. I just want to create a view(white one) similar to the image. With the wavy top.

Comment: refer this link : https://medium.com/@GultekinGokhan/how-to-use-b%C3%A9zier-curve-in-your-real-world-ios-projects-694090957e3e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method below will let you add the background wave effect to another `view`.  All you then need to do for the foreground square is add another view.  Play with the constants to change the wave shape/height.

```
func addWaveBackground(to view: UIView){
      let leftDrop:CGFloat = 0.4
      let rightDrop: CGFloat = 0.3
      let leftInflexionX: CGFloat = 0.4
      let leftInflexionY: CGFloat = 0.47
      let rightInflexionX: CGFloat = 0.6
      let rightInflexionY: CGFloat = 0.22

      let backView = UIView(frame: view.frame)
      backView.backgroundColor = .gray
      view.addSubview(backView)
      let backLayer = CAShapeLayer()
      let path = UIBezierPath()
      path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
      path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:0, y: view.frame.height * leftDrop))
      path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x:view.frame.width, y: view.frame.height * rightDrop),
                    controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: view.frame.width * leftInflexionX, y: view.frame.height * leftInflexionY),
                    controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: view.frame.width * rightInflexionX, y: view.frame.height * rightInflexionY))
      path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:view.frame.width, y: 0))
      path.close()
      backLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
      backLayer.path = path.cgPath
      backView.layer.addSublayer(backLayer)
   }
```

Pass in the view you want to add the wave effect to (this will usually be the VC's main view).